# Angular JS directive, calling another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to implement a simple <pagination> directive in Angular JS, and having trouble getting it to communicate with another controller to get it to react on changes to the current page.

Here's what my code looks like:

**paginationDirective.js**

```
app.controller('paginationCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.init = function (attrs) {
        $scope.items = [
            {'page': '1', class: 'current'},
            {'page': '2', class: ''},
            {'page': '3', class: ''},
            {'page': '4', class: ''},
            {'page': '5', class: ''}
        ];
    };
});

app.directive('pagination', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'paginationCtrl',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            count: '@',
            page: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/pagination.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, paginationCtrl) {
            paginationCtrl.init(attrs);
        }
    }
});
```

**pagination.html**

```
<div class="pagination-centered">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="{{ item.class }}">
            <a href="" ng-click="<!-- somepageCtrl.navigate(item.page) -->">{{ item.page }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**somepage.html**

```
<div class="content">
    <table>...data for page x...</table>

    <pagination onpage=" <!-- Run somepageCtrl.page(x) --> "></pagination>
</div>
```

**somepageCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('somepageCtrl', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    $scope.init = function () {
        myService.loadData($scope);
    };

    $scope.navigate = function(page) {
        console.log('Navigating to page ' + page);
    }

    $scope.init();
});
```

I'm still new to AngularJS, so I'm not entirely sure what I should do to get the pagination directive to tell somepageCtrl to navigate to the next page.

I would like to be able to pass a function that needs to be executed when the user clicks an item in the pagination directive as an attribute on the directive.

Can anyone help and nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is `somepageCtrl` set?

Comment: It's set on $routeProvider. The page executes, I'm just not sure how to get the directive to tell the controller to reload with next page's data from server.

Comment: For `<pagination onpage=" <!-- Run somepageCtrl.page(x) --> "></pagination>` did you mean `somepageCtrl.navigate(x)`?

Comment: Yes, I put it in comments to indicate it's pseudo code. Sorry for the weird convention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the experession callback `&` to call your controller back from a directive.

**pagination directive**

```
app.directive('pagination', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'paginationCtrl',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            count: '@',
            page: '@',
            onPageChange: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/pagination.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, paginationCtrl) {
            paginationCtrl.init(attrs);

           // grab function pointer so it will be called  correctly with ng-click
           scope.onPageChange = scope.onPageChange();
        }
    }
});
```

**somepage.html**

```
<div class="content">
    <table>...data for page x...</table>

    <pagination on-page-change="sompageCtrl.navigate"></pagination>
</div>
```

**pagination.html**

```
<div class="pagination-centered">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="{{ item.class }}">
            <a href="" ng-click="onPageChange(item.page)">{{ item.page }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Getting a "$scope is not defined". I tried passing $scope to app.directive, but not sure it works that way here. I also changed $scope.onPageChange = $scope.onPageChange(); to scope.onPageChange = scope.onPageChange(); but no luck. I have defined .navigate on somepageCtrl without any luck so far. Reading up to try and find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question, thanks to Esteban Felix for pointing me into the right direction.

I defined the navigate() method on somepageCtrl:

```
$scope.navigate = function (page) {
    console.log('Lets go to page ' + page);
};
```

then simply added the function to

```
<pagination on-change="navigate"></pagination>
```

The method then gets assigned in the app.directive definition like so:

```
scope: {
    count: '@',
    page: '@',
    onChange: '&onChange'
},
```

On the app.controller for paginationCtrl, I created a callback function:

```
$scope.callback = function (page) {
    console.log('Turn to page ' + page);
    $scope.onChange()(page);
}
```

and updated the markup for pagination.html to call the above callback with ng-click like so:

```
<a href="" ng-click="callback(item.page)">{{ item.page }}</a>
```